# NSUserDefaults saves details sometimes and doesn't someother times

Tags: ios, exception, nsuserdefaults, crash

I use NSUserDefaults to save some data locally. But the problem is it doesn't save the data all the times.

For instance:

While an app is crashing I save the execption related informations using NSUserDefaults

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&onUncaughtException);

}

void onUncaughtException(NSException* exception)
{
 //save exception related details using NSuserdefaults
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have to `synchronize` thne `NSUserDefaults` while crashing.Since you are not doing that, the exception details disappear

Call the `synchronize` method on app termination:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```